# What (Numeric(18,0), Null) should be converted to in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here's my method:

```
public static newCase GetCaseById(string id)
{
        using (var db = myDbContext.Create())
        {
            Guid _id;
            if (Guid.TryParse(id, out _id))
            {
                var _case = db.NewCases.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == _id); ??
                return _case;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

`The 'Case_id' property on 'newCases' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'.`

Yet, the **Case_id** column is well defined in the **newCase** class.

```
public class newCase
{
   public double Case_id { get; set; }

   //more here...
}
```

In the table **Case_id** is defined as `CaseId(Numeric(18, 0), NULL)`.

I've changed case_id from d**ouble** to **double?** without success. What's the problem?

Thanks for helping

Comment: A number with 18 digits is quite excessive and can't practically be used to count something.  Surely they use some kind of digit grouping like an SSN (123-45-6789) or a telephone number?  High odds it should be string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation, a Numeric value in the database should be reflected as Decimal in .Net

So my recommendation is to change your

```
public double Case_id { get; set; }
```

to

```
public Decimal Case_id { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just set the property to `public double Case_id { get; set; }`. Why am I even getting this type of error: `could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value....`. It's kind of absurd. Is EF reading a different definition?

Comment: Because the type in the database is not the SQL equivalent of a double, but the SQL equivalent of a Decimal.

Comment: I noticed that all the columns causing problems have small values. None of them has a value with more that 4 digits. So, I changed them from `Number(18, 0)` to `INT` int the database. They are all working now. I wonder whether that's the reason EF is complainging.

Comment: Just for understanding the difference, float / double are floating point types, while decimal / numeric (and int implictly) are fixed point.

If you just need integers, definitely stay with such solution